# PHP Returns Proper JSON, but it break jQuery $.each function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using

```
 $.each(txt2,function(index,item){
$("#selectSection").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.sectionId).text(item.sectionText));
```

It works if I hard code the following json:

```
 [{"sectionId":"1","sectionText":"Section One"},{"sectionId":"2","sectionText":"Section Two"},{"sectionId":"3","sectionText":"Section Three"},{"sectionId":"4","sectionText":"Section Four"},{"sectionId":"5","sectionText":"Hull"},{"sectionId":"6","sectionText":"Topside"}]
```

However, when PHP returns the json is includes the name of the multi array as follows, which breaks the code.

```
 {"sections":[{"sectionId":"1","sectionText":"Section One"},{"sectionId":"2","sectionText":"Section Two"},{"sectionId":"3","sectionText":"Section Three"},{"sectionId":"4","sectionText":"Section Four"},{"sectionId":"5","sectionText":"Hull"},{"sectionId":"6","sectionText":"Topside"}]}
```

Any ideas?

For background, below is the code I am using.  The code works perfectly with the actual ajax query result commented out and the json hard coded in.  I am providing it only for background.

```
$.ajax({
url:"querySections3.php",
datatype: "json",
success:function(result){
  //txt1 = result;
    txt2 = [{"sectionId":"1","sectionText":"Section One"},{"sectionId":"2","sectionText":"Section Two"},{"sectionId":"3","sectionText":"Section Three"},{"sectionId":"4","sectionText":"Section Four"},{"sectionId":"5","sectionText":"Hull"},{"sectionId":"6","sectionText":"Topside"}]
 //options = JSON.parse(txt1);          
   $.each(txt2,function(index,item){
    $("#selectSection").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.sectionId).text(item.sectionText));
   });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `$.each` doesn't deal with JSON. So figure out what the *actual data is* (e.g. use the web-browser debugger) and why it "doesn't work". In this case it simply looks like the code is simply *not* processing the data meaningfully with the "failing data".

Comment: try `result.sections` like `txt1 = result.sections` then `$.each(txt1, function(){})`

Comment: Why is PHP returning an object if you just want an array?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just dereference the inner array:

```
options = JSON.parse(txt1).sections;
$.each(options,function(index,item){
```

You could also change the data structure on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your PHP JSON output according to the structure that you need, but in case that it's not viable then you can adjust your javascript code to iterate `sections` instead of the root. Also, you don't need to parse a JSON string in javascript.

```
$.ajax({
url:"querySections3.php",
datatype: "json",
success:function(result){
    txt1 = result;
   $.each(txt1["sections"],function(index,item){
    $("#selectSection").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.sectionId).text(item.sectionText));
   });
```